# how to Create table dynamically and add button in specific table column asp.net c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have written following code to create table column and added button. When I click this button, it does not call OnClick function.

```
Panel2.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<tr><td>" + Convert.ToString(x) + "</td><th>" + Convert.ToString(Session["student_enrollment"]) + " </th><td>" + Convert.ToString(Session["student_name"]) + "</td><td>" + Convert.ToString(Session["student_program"]) + "</td>
<td>
    <asp:Button class=\"btn btn-primary\" runat=\"server\" OnClick=\"setup_defense_Click\">Setup Defense</asp:Button></td></tr>"));
```

[Result is shown below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSlNz.png)

Comment: Please show the code for your onclick action.

Comment: Try adding () to your OnClick method so it becomes `setup_defense_Click()` and make sure the spelling is correct

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are adding these buttons after the `Page_Load` event of the page life cycle, this code will not work because when the control is rendered, `ViewState` for the page has already been restored/created. To make your code work, try rendering these buttons in the `Page_Init` event of the page life-cycle. If somehow, you don't have the option to do that, you can always create an HTML button and use AJAX calls to communicate with a method on the code-behind file.